# django debug toolbar: no such session

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5swj5.png)I've been trying to set up the Django debug toolbar. I follow every step in documentation, I add the path in urls.py I add the middleware I add the debugtoolbar in Installed apps, but yet I come up with this error:
**Operational error :
no such table : django_session**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run this in your project terminal

python manage.py migrate
and not
python manage.py makemigrations